# Can't get fold gutter to show in CodeMirror in xml mode

Tags: javascript, xml, codemirror

I'm trying to create a CodeMirror editor for some XML content with the fold gutter showing. I'm loading a bunch of codemirror library code (version 3.18):

```JavaScript
<script src="js/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/foldcode.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/xml-fold.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/foldgutter.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/xml.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/sparql.js"></script>
```

And then I create the editor object:

```JavaScript
var showCodeMirrorResult = function( code, count, mode ) {
  var editor = CodeMirror( $("#results").get(0), {
    value: code,
    mode: mode,
    lineNumbers: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": function(cm){ cm.foldCode(cm.getCursor()); }},
    foldGutter: true,
    gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"]
  } );
};
```

where `code` is a string encoding an XML document, and `mode` is `application/xml`. This all works - I get a syntax-highlighted CodeMirror editor, I can use ctl-Q to fold and unfold XML nodes, all good. However, I **can't** get the gutter to show, indicating to the user that folding is something they can do in this editor. I'm expecting [something like this](http://codemirror.net/demo/folding.html) - note the triangles in the LH gutter to indicate fold points. I can't get those to appear, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you add CSS?

```
 .CodeMirror-foldmarker {    
    font-family: arial;
  }
 .CodeMirror-foldgutter {
    width: .7em;
  }
  .CodeMirror-foldgutter-open,
  .CodeMirror-foldgutter-folded {
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .CodeMirror-foldgutter-open:after {
    content: "\25BE";
  }
  .CodeMirror-foldgutter-folded:after {
    content: "\25B8";
  }
```

Comment: I hadn't spotted the CSS (which is only included in the example, and not mentioned in the documentation anywhere that I could see). However, it doesn't help: if I eval `$(".CodeMirror-foldgutter")` in the Chrome console, it selects an empty set of elements. So somehow the gutter is not being added in the first place.

Comment: $(".CodeMirror-foldgutter") shouldn't be empty. It is going to be difficult to find out the cause of this problem without seeing the code.

Comment: OK, so the missing CSS was actually the problem. The reason I thought that it wasn't was that I had a couple of experimental git branches going, and in the one where I tried adding the CSS rules as suggested, I had another bug (missing `gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"],` which masked the problem - and was the cause of the jQuery expression returning empty.